# XMPP server software recommendations

Tags: xmpp

We are wanting to run our own XMPP server at our office for various things.  Internal communication, automatic notifications from our software applications etc.  I would prefer to run this in Windows but I can spin up a VM and run Linux if the Windows options all suck.  I have come across sites like: http://www.saint-andre.com/jabber/jsc/ and was curious if anyone has any experience with any of these or if anyone has any recommendations.  My budget consists of $0 so most likely an open source solution may be my only option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest Openfire http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp

I have used Openfire on both Windows and Linux for the last year and a half and it has been a rock solid jabber server.

Comment: I second the use of Openfire

Answer (score 3):

I like [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) a lot; it just works. It is even easy to migrate from jabberd. Don't know how/if it runs well on Windows though, I use Debian GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jabberd2 in windows with http://www.nanoant.com/projects/jabberd2-win32